# Lower CPU % used by FFMPEG Process via PHP (FLV Video Conversion)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, cpu, cpu-usage

Okay, so I currently execute an ffmpeg command via PHP to run a video conversion. The Problem I'm Having is during the conversion, the ffmpeg process(es) use up so much CPU/Processing Power (near 100%), which slows down the response of my webserver.

Is there a Way (crontab or script) I can limit the ffmpeg processes to a certain CPU percentage?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What platform? I assume from "crontab" that you're on Linux, in which case you can run ffmpeg using [nice](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/nice/). That is, instead of:

> ffmpeg (options)

Run:

> nice -n 20 ffmpeg (options)

This will run ffmpeg at the lowest possible priority, which means any other processing (e.g. web pages) will get scheduled ahead of ffmpeg. It'll still run at "100%" but it'll never take time away from higher priority tasks, which is what you want.

Comment: I tried to run that via PHP but it doesn't even run it :(  
I've tried the exec(), shell_exec(), and system() functions....it just wont work :(  I've also tried to code a script to use a utility called "cpulimit"...and that works for the first process only....grrrr! haha